# Electric Range Outlet Wiring

Tags: electrical

US 1976 built: My 3 prong range outlet has an additional thinner gauge ground wire.  How do I connect this wire?

[image]

Comment: What does the plug from the range look like?

Comment: Seize the opportunity to upgrade to a 4-prong outlet and cord!  That one is a simple wire break away from killing you.

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow questions and then below I also posted the back story on this outlet.  1) The ground wire is only 12 gauge - is that OK? 2) I don't have a 4 prong outlet yet but some say all wires have to be a lower(thicker) gauge to connect to the outlet. If so, do I use a pigtail and wire nut to make thicker?                                                                Now the backstory. I am the original 1976 owner and the range and outlet are original. The place was brand new, and I was actually shocked by touching the range which the builder then fixed.

Comment: I am fairly certain the ground wire here needs to be at least **10** AWG. 12 is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Modern (last 25+ years) ranges are supposed to be connected with a 4-wire connection - hot/hot/neutral/ground. This is a NEMA 14 receptacle.

In the past, a 3-wire connection - hot/hot/neutral - was allowed. This is a NEMA-10 receptacle.

You are allowed to continue using the old NEMA 10, which is why they still exist. However, all equipment (ranges, clothes dryers) for many years has been designed to connect with either type of cord/plug with very little effort.

In your particular case, it appears that you have a NEMA 10-50 receptacle. However, the ground wire **with a loop** indicates that previously the ground wire had been in use. Which means you previously had a NEMA 14-50 receptacle and then someone bought a range that came with a 3-wire plug. Instead of replacing the cord/plug for a 4-wire cord/plug (which involves swapping a few screw terminated wires and, importantly, removing the neutral/ground bonding jumper), they swapped the receptacle for a 3-wire receptacle.

Replace the receptacle with a 4-wire NEMA 14-50 [like this one](https://amzn.to/3jbGxvB):

[image: Leviton 14-50]

(You can get them anywhere, Amazon just happens to have easy to upload pictures - but make sure it is UL or ETL listed.)

If your range has a NEMA 10-50 plug, you will need to replace the cord & plug with a NEMA 14-50 plug [like this](https://amzn.to/3lPi7d3):

[image: Southwire NEMA 14-50 cord/plug]

and remove the grounding wire/jumper. If you are not sure how to remove the grounding wire/jumper, post a new question and include the range make/model #.

Comment: Thank you and very helpful! I have a follow up question and then I posted the back story on this outlet.